# Isosceles triangle in circle with angle and text - in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, nodes, circles

Im a newcomer to tikz and I've been playing around with it for some time now.

For some presentation I need a representation of an isosceles triangle in the unit circle. The only thing I got so far was the circle (Sorry for that). I wasn't even able to place some proper nodes connected by lines with text. It would be fabulous if the angle could also be marked.

I added some self-drawn picture for explanation. The exact angle of alpha doesn't matter so much. My rather sad MWE is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Isosceles triangle]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
line cap=round,
MA/.style = {% My Angle
        draw, 
        angle radius=3mm, angle eccentricity=1.5,
        font=\small}
                        ]
\draw (0,0) coordinate[label=180:C] (C) circle[radius=1];
%
\draw (C) -- ++ ( 45:1) coordinate[label= 45:A] (A);
\draw (C) -- ++ (330:1) coordinate[label=330:B] (B);
\draw (A) -- (B);
\pic [MA,  "$\gamma$"]  {angle =B--C--A};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you not like labels at triangle's corners, delete `[label=...]`.

Comment: I somehow get a nasty error on the line `pic [MA,  "$\gamma$"]  {angle =B--C--A};`

Resulting in: 
Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.

Comment: @NoteMyQuestion, no with my suggestion as it is. You probably add `babel` package to my MWE (Minimal Working Example), which can change meaning of some symbols (like `''`) in `tikzpicture`.  A cure can be adding ˙babel` library to `\usetikzlibrary`. Please tell me, if my guessing is correct.

Comment: you were correct, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Just for comparison, here is a version in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) wrapped up in `luamplib`; compile with `lualatex`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    path O; O = fullcircle scaled 7 cm; % keep center at origin
    numeric alpha; alpha = 82;

    z0 = origin;
    z1 = point -0.4 of O;
    z2 = z1 rotated alpha;

    draw O withcolor 2/3 blue;
    draw fullcircle scaled 42 rotated angle z1 cutafter (z0 -- z2) withpen pencircle scaled 1/4;
    draw z0 -- z1 -- z2 -- cycle;
    forsuffixes $=0, 1, 2: 
        drawdot z$ withpen pencircle scaled dotlabeldiam; 
    endfor

    label.llft("$1$", 1/2[z0, z1]);
    label.ulft("$1$", 1/2[z0, z2]);
    label.urt("$c$", 1/2[z1, z2]);

    label("$\alpha$", 12 unitvector(z1 + z2));

    % add graph paper
    picture T; T = currentpicture; 
    currentpicture := nullpicture;
    for t=-10 upto 10:
        draw (left--right) scaled 10cm shifted (0, t * 5mm) withcolor 7/8 white;
        draw (up--down) scaled 10cm shifted (t * 5mm, 0) withcolor 7/8 white;
    endfor
    interim bboxmargin := 2mm;
    clip currentpicture to bbox T;
    draw T;
    
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I not forgot yet your complete answer for the arrow on photon with feynmp :-)